# :disabled => true & :disabled => "disabled" don't make collection_select disabled in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2

This is my collection_select :

```
<%= f.collection_select(:country_id, {}, :id, {}, 
   :prompt => 'Select Country First', :disabled => 'disabled') %>
```

- adding :disabled => true  / :disabled => "disabled" don't **REALLY** disable the dropdowns.
- Adding a blank hash({}) and prompting a default message "select...." just makes it feel our dropdown is disabled.
- Hence none of above options really mark dropdown disabled.
- Any options there to make this collection_select disabled( No back biting via jquery), need solution via any parameter to this collection_select.

Answer (score 0):

you have an exta `}` in your `collection_select` statement, also you can try the following

> 'Select Country First', {disabled: [options_you_want_as_disabled] }) %>

note that `:disabled` - can be a single value or an array of values that will be disabled options in the final output.

Comment: for some reason this line is not visible, dont know why..:(

`<%= f.collection_select(:country_id, {}, :id, {}, `